# How do i check if an indexed part of a list has a value or string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make connect 4 and having some issues.

Lets say, player one puts their counter in `row[4]column[3]`
before player 2 plays, **I wanna be able to check and see if the position player 2 wants to put their counter in is not already taken**.

This will prevent overriding

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do? You simply test the coordinates at which user 1 placed their piece. If it is filled with whatever character you're using to represent a piece, then you know its filled.

Comment: Rather than having the player select a row and column, they should probably just select a column and it will fill in first available row.

Comment: Could you add some code you've already written? Then we can more clearly see what you're trying to do.

Comment: @James Yes that's the ideal situation, but i don't even know if that's possible with just text base programming and i'm also not sure how to implement that

Comment: @bigblind it's a lot of code because i've imported different files into the main doc to make this work so it's not straightforward to give you a piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to see the code you've already implemented.

If each column is a list, let's call it `col`, for this example, then you could check whether `col[i] is None` to see if the value at index `i` is equal to `None`. If you want to see whether the value at that location is a string, you could check whether `isinstance(col[i], basestring)`, but since you're not putting arbitrary values in there, that's probably not your best option.

---

Update: From your comment it seems you use a space, `" "`, as an empty square. Why not just check `col[i] == " "` then?

Comment: `col[i] is None` is the closest thing to what i'm looking for but the only problem is that every grid position all have spaces in between them so  `col[i] is None` returns `False` by default because a space is treated like a string

Comment: In that case, you should be able to just check for equality to a space. `col[i] == " "`.

Comment: PERFECT!! that did it. Thanks buddy